# Recovering netbeans local history

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu

I had a Virtual Machine inside which I had my PHP project. The project was developed using Netbeans, and I used its local history extensively.

My VM Ubuntu installation got corrupted, so I ended up creating a new VM. I was able to copy over most of the files from the VDI (I attached it to the new VM), but I can't figure out where netbeans' local history is saved. I copied over the Netbeans project folder, but the history doesn't seem to be saved here.

Does anybody know how I can recover the Netbeans history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local History is kept in the .netbeans settings folder.  On my Windows 7 machine that is located at `<HOME>/.netbeans/<NB_VERSION>/var/filehistory` where `HOME` is my user home and `NB_VERSION` is the version of NetBeans (e.g. 7.0).

Unfortunately this is an all or nothing thing.  There is no way, that I can tell, to find specific projects.  So, if you have local history for projects on your host machine you run the risk of overwriting these.

Comment: That did it! Found the .netbeans folder in my Linux home folder!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for it on a Mac, the file local history is located at /Library/Application Support/Netbeans//var/filehistory.